# How to restrict access to wp-content, wp-includes and all sub-folders

Tags: htaccess, directory, nofollow

after searching I didn't find an answer still confused of how do I hide the
-> wp-content
--> uploads
--> themes
--> plugins
-> wp-includes in browser. What I want is when viewer browse some like this: http://www.mysite.ext/wp-content they will see an error: **You don't have permission to access this page**.
Other said that just upload index.html or index.php with .htaccess in the folder you want to hide. But what if I have many subfolder inside wp-content I will do that every folder manually? Or there is a way either in *cpanel*, or in *.htaccess* ? Suggestion please, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use in your .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
```

… to disable directory listings. See the [Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) for details.

To restrict the access just to two URLs you might use:

```
RedirectMatch 204 ^/wp-content/$
RedirectMatch 204 ^/wp-content/dir/$
```

`204` is the *No Content* response. Very fast. :)